# How are values greater than 4 bits stored in 4 bit assembly?

Tags: assembly, numbers, bit

I've been thinking about assembly lately and I can't wrap my head around how values greater than 4 bits were stored and used in 4 bit assembly.  It seems to me like you would only be able to use the values 0 - 15 in 4 bit assembly, but I've seen values that are obviously greater than 15 used.  Also by 4 bit assembly I mean 8 bits total.  4 for the instruction and 4 for the operand, such as 0000 0000.

Comment: You mean like the Intel 4004 CPU? In any case, you can make numbers of as much length as memory will hold, as long as arithmetic operations on them use loops.

Answer (score 0):

There are different solutions for encoding `immediates` in assembly languages:
In CISC machines, variable-length instructions usually allow machine-word sized immediates to be encoded in an instruction that is then naturally longer than a machine word (opcode + immediate). On RISC machines, fixed-length instructions usually preclude loading machine-word immediates. Instead, multiple instructions load parts of the immediate into a register. For example, on 32-bit MIPS, loading a 32-bit value is done by

```
lui $reg, (16-bit immediate upper half)
ori $reg, (16-bit immediate lower half)
```

The use of a register is acceptable, because RISC computers tend to have a lot of them.